# How to implement search page via TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make a search page. Made by means of TextField a field on clicking on which the page of search should open. Tell me how to implement clicking on the TextField and so that the back button appears on the left and the buttons disappear on the right?

**code**

```
TextFormField(
                style: constants.Styles.textFieldTextStyleWhite,
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 15, // HERE THE IMPORTANT PART
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    prefixIcon: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          constants.Assets.search,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20,
                        ))),
              )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap everything into a `StatefulWidget`.

Then, when clicking the `TextFormField`, change the attributes of the `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {

  var myBool = false;
  
  // Initialize your Row-buttons here
  // ...

  void changeRow(){
    setState(() {
 
     // Hide or show Row-buttons here.   

     myBool = true;

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Scaffold(
         body: Row(children:[

             myBool == true 
               ? Icon( ...)         // shows icon
               : SizedBox.shrink(), // shows nothing

             TextFormField( onTap: () => changeRow() ),

             // other BUTTONs here
         ])
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are a few possibilities for an AppBar to show Text or Buttons.

Check these examples:

https://www.fluttercampus.com/tutorial/10/flutter-appbar/

Comment: And if the search bar is not in my appbar, but just on the page itself? Or is there no difference?

Comment: Not a big difference, instead of an `AppBar` just use a `Row(children:[ ... ])`. It boils down to the same approach.v See updated answer.

Comment: I can initialize the true/false variable and change the value on click and change the widget depending on the value

Comment: Tell me, if I need to open a page with a search by clicking on the Textfield, how can I implement it?

Comment: @Max By using a navigator and call it from inside the click-function. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: I just ran into a problem that I can not put the showSearch method in the TextField method. I need to open a page with a search when clicking on a TextField

Comment: Use a `GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () { ... navigate ... },
                      child: TextFormField() )`